# How can I do automatic eager loading for ALL associated objects with MongoDB/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a model which may have multiple models associated using belongs to. How can I automatically do eager loading and get all records with their associated records? If this is not possible, any idea how I can make this work? My model is very dynamic - models will be added during runtime or removed so I cannot explicitely use the model names within an include instruction.

I have another model called Entity which describes all of my models (which fields are in the model, what association exist), so I could worst case lookup my model and loop over all associations - but I am afraid this will be very unperformant this weay.

**Update**

I thought a tackle this problem step by step so I first tried to get eager loading work at all (after reading tons of articles about this) but I still do not get it running. I have a model Entity:

```
class Entity
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    field :label, type: String
    field :description, type: String
    field :typ, type: String

    belongs_to :user
end
```

And I have a model User:

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :username, type: String
    field :name, type: String
    field :email, type: String
    has_many :entities
end
```

Now I have a controller function getAll which expects the model name I want to retrieve (in this case here I call it with {object: 'Entity'}

```
def getAll
    obj = params.require(:object)
    datarecord = obj.classify.constantize
    render json: { result: datarecord.includes(:user).all()}
end
```

I would expect now to get all records from my Entity model and each record including the associated user. But using includes(:user) or not doesnt make a difference. I always only get all entity records and no user information.

**Further Update**

Looks like the eager loading is all working but the problem is not MongoDB!

If I add datarecord[:user] = datarecord.user I will have the user data included without any MongoDB activity. Unfortunately it wont be embedded in my response as user: { ...} but as user_id: {...}.

Why are the user data not automatically included? Is there a way to do this automatically for all association and also to have it rendered under the object name not under the id?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: MongoDB 3.2 introduced aggregate queries but I'm not sure if Mongoid supports it or if you can actually do anything which resembles eager loading in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Hi Max, I uodated my problem - seems eager loading was working but the problem is somewhere else